# Limit the character in HTML column

Tags: html, css

Hello I have a table that look like this

[image: HTML table]

I want to limit the number of characters within each column, so it will display properly, in this picture I haven't included any space to it, so it did not go into the next line when it reach the max-width.

and this is my css code.

```
#table-main {
    width: 740px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 2px;
}

#table-main th {
    max-width: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #B22222;
    background: #7fd9c1;
    text-align: left;
}

#table-main tr.holiday td {
   background: #ffc0cb;
}

#table-main td {
   max-width: 50px;
   padding: 5px;
   background: #D1EEEE;
   text-align: left;
   table-layout:fixed
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Any idea how to achieve it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it will break by the word as well as wrap the content

```
word-break: break-all;
word-wrap:break-word;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the overflow option to hide anything that does not fit in the column.

overflow: Hidden;

You can find more details at [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)